# Making a deck of cards on Java using arrays and objects?

Tags: java, arrays, object, playing-cards

My textbook gave me this code saying that it'll create a new set of 52 cards. I don't really understand what it does, because the methods I see on google is very different from this. I'm confused about what the "index" variable does and how can I print this method? I do have a printdeck method but how would I call that method if this method doesn't return any number?

```
 public static void buildDeck () {
    Card[] deck = new Card [52];
 int index = 0;
 for (int suit = 0; suit <=3; suit++) {
     for (int rank = 1; rank <= 13; rank++) {
         deck[index] = new Card (suit, rank);
         index++;
     }

}

//here is my printDeck method
public static void printCard (Card c) {
    String[] suits = { "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades" };
    String [] ranks = { "nart", "Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "jack", "Queen", "king" };
    System.out.println (ranks[c.rank] + " of " + suits[c.suit]);
}
public static void printDeck (Card[] deck) {
    for (int i = 0; i< deck.length; i++) {
        printCard (deck[i]);
    }
}
```

I'll appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't your textbook also explain what the code does? Also it's a bit unclear where exactly your issue is - `index` is just an `int` variable (that is used to access elements in the array)

Comment: That buildDeck method can't be right. As soon as the method is finished, the deck variable will be out of scope and inaccessible.

Comment: Build a private deck and immediately throw it away???  Your  **textbook** gave you that amateur-hour garbage?  I think you need a better textbook!

Comment: @UnholySheep the textbook basically just says this is the method I should use, it doesn't really say more

Comment: @celinatala, well, if it says you **should** use this, then I'd be pretty safe to say that you should ignore what that book says.

Answer (score 0):

The index variable, like the name states, is used as a counting index for the deck.

The printDeck(..) method should print the whole to the console by calling the printCard(..) method and that method in return calling `System.out.println`

Answer (score 0):

- The method `printDeck` doesn not really print something to the console. It takes an array of cards and calls for each card the method `printCard` (supplying the current card as argument).
- The method `printCard` takes - as mentioned before - a single card and prints its rank /suite to the console.

  public static void printCard (Card c) {
    System.out.println (ranks[c.rank] + " of " + suits[c.suit]);
  }

The `index` variable is used e.g. to initialize the deck of cards.

- Initially you have 52 "blank" cards in the array, or better said each entry in the array is null.
- In each iteration you are creating a `new Card` and have to assign it to a position in the deck. This is done via the `index` and by incrementing it with each iteration.

Comment: When I print the buildDeck method, why does it only print the "club" suits? And there is an error in between 2 of clubs and 3 of clubs saying "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException"?

Comment: I suggest that you use a debugger to figure out the cause of the NullPointerException. The exception could also explain why you only the the clubs.

Answer (score 0):

You should return card[] deck from your buildDeck method and then pass it to print method.